# Triggering AWS codepipeline with regex matching tag push with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

I have a problem to setting config terraform with trigger CodePipeline, I can't find config terraform, I use AWS CodePipeline with V2

[image]

I tried this config, Don't work

```
resource "aws_codepipeline_webhook" "gitlab_webhook" {
  name               = "gitlab-webhook"
  authentication     = "UNAUTHENTICATED" # GitLab webhook also uses GITHUB_HMAC authentication method
  target_pipeline    = aws_codepipeline.codepipeline.name
  target_action      = "Source"

  filter {
    json_path    = "$.ref"
    match_equals = "refs/heads/main"
  }
}
```

Comment: This feature has not yet been implemented as you can see in [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/35475) issue on GitHub.